# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lEGL

Tags: apt

I did install `libegl1-mesa` and `libegl1-mesa-dev` on my ubuntu platform. But when I run the sample code from [nvdiffrast](https://nvlabs.github.io/nvdiffrast/), there is a error and reports `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lEGL`. How can I fix this plz?

Comment: BTW, I have googled some advice. Most of them required me to install the missing package. Maybe `libegl1-mesa` and `libegl1-mesa-dev` are not the right packages. But the commands, including `apt-get install libEGL`, `apt-get install libegl` and `apt-get install libegl1` all failed.

Comment: What is your OS? What do you mean by "failed"?

Comment: You also misspell package names. The package is `libgl1-mesa-dev`, not `libegl1-mesa-dev`

Comment: OS:16.04.1-Ubuntu. "failed" means I couldn't install these package because of `Unable to locate package`. I rechecked the installed package and `libgl1-mesa-dev` was installed. But `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lEGL` still exists.

Comment: 16.04 is off-topic here.